# Ubuntu16.10: install GDAL on Python3.6

Tags: gdal, installation, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I am on Ubuntu16.10. I would like to install `GDAL` on `Python3.6`. 
I have installed Python3.6 with `apt-get install python3.6`. 
I am installing `GDAL` with:

```
apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal
```

The problem is that in this way, `GDAL` is installed on `python3.5` not on the `3.6`.
The problem seems to be `python3-gdal`, because:

```
apt show python3-gdal
```

gives:

```
Package: python3-gdal
Version: 2.2.1+dfsg-2build3
Priority: optional
Section: universe/python
Source: gdal
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian GIS Project <pkg-grass-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 2242 kB
Provides: python3.5-gdal
```

On Ubuntu16.10 it provides `python3.5-gdal`. Is there a way to force it to provide `python3.6-gdal`?

Comment: Suggest you upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu. 16.10 is [end of life](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/07/20/ubuntu-16-10-yakkety-yak-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2017/) as of 20 July 2017.

Comment: @Luke I have compatibility issues with some software, that's why I am stuck for the moment with 16.10

Comment: You still can put a current build of Ubuntu, gdal and python in a virtual box under your 16.10 host OS. Otherwise, you have to build gdal from source.

Comment: BTW adding ubuntugis unstable ppa is useless becuse that does not support Ubuntu 16.10. And I wonder where you got GDAL 2.2.1 from. The main ubuntu repo lists that for artful (17.10) only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get your preferred GDAL/Python version without the restrictions imposed by your system package manager is to use the [`conda`](https://conda.io/docs/) package management system.  You can use this without admin/root privileges as it installs to your home directory and you don't run the risk of messing up your system by installing a non-standard system python.

1. Install [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)
2. Create a conda environment:

   - `conda create -n mygdalenv gdal python=3.6` or
   - `conda create -c conda-forge -n mygdalenv gdal python=3.6`
3. Activate your new environment:

   - `source activate mygdalenv`

If you want an IDE, you can use PyCharm with your new environment (`sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic`), or you can activate it manually then `conda install spyder`, or if you prefer Jupyter notebooks `conda install jupyter`